# pylint without user site directory?

Tags: python, pylint

My installation of `pylint` started to behave strangely. It complained that packgages that were present could not be imported. I found the problem in the `pylint` script's shebang line:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3 -sP
```

where the `-s` option has following meaning:

> ```
> -s  Don't add user site directory to sys.path
> ```

It does not make any sense to me. I removed the `-s` and I'm able to check my programs again. Could somebody please explain the logic behind it?

The system in question is Fedora 39, `pylint` was installed from Fedora RPMs.

---

UPDATE: **It was a bug** and Fedora will release a fixed version soon.

Comment: Could you add a link to the bug report?

Comment: Hre you are: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2256378